# Deployment of Rails website on Heroku errors

Tags: ruby, heroku

Trying to finally deploy to Heroku, but I have two messages which seem like red flags, and ultimately the deployment does not work. 
ERROR 1,  that I see (after : `$ git push heroku master`)

```
remote:        Detecting rails configuration failed
remote:        set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
```

When i use the `heroku logs --tail`
ERROR 2:

```
2018-10-30T07:18:41.859565+00:00 app[web.1]: COMPILATION ERROR: error executing "gcc -shared  -Wl,--compress-debug-sections=zlib -fPIC -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wduplicated-cond -Wrestrict -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-linux -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/include -L/app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib -o \"/app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.5.0/Inline_String_9a6686966a50705d94442f198bc2c408.so\" \"/app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.5.0/Inline_String_9a6686966a50705d94442f198bc2c408.c\"  ": pid 8 exit 127
```

ERROR 3, much below in the logs:

```
2018-10-30T07:18:49.967238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-10-30T07:18:51.776458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=XXXXXXXXXXXX dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-30T07:19:00.599846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"  host=XXXXXXXXXXXX dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-30T07:19:26.069175+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host= host=XXXXXXXXXXXX dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-30T07:20:18.694993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host= host=XXXXXXXXXXXX dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-30T07:20:22.175572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host= host=XXXXXXXXXXXX dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

These errors are fairly difficult to relate to as it is the first time for me. Is anyone familiar with them ?

Comment: There should be more info the logs

Comment: Hi Emaillenin, yes but it would take a few pages to display, so I took only the red lines. It is not enough ?